# GCC preprocessor directives for Arch Linux

Tags: c, linux, c-preprocessor, archlinux

Does GCC (or alternatively Clang) defines any macro when it is compiled for the Arch Linux OS?

I need to check that my software restricts itself from compiling under anything but Arch Linux (the reason behind this is off-topic). I couldn't find any relevant resources on the internet.

Does anyone know how to guarantee through GCC preprocessor directives that my binaries are only compilable under Arch Linux?

Of course I can always

```c
#ifdef __linux__
  ...
#endif
```

But this is not precise enough.

Edit: This **must** be done through C source code and not by any building systems, so, for example, doing this through CMake is completely discarded.

Edit 2: Users faking this behaviour is not a problem since the software is distributed to selected clients and thus, actively trying to "misuse" our source code is "their decision".

Comment: why do you need it to be so specific? What can run on Arch but not on other distros?

Comment: As noted in the answer, please clarify whether you want to make sure it is only *compiled* on Arch, or only *run* on Arch.  Also, how concerned are you about the user trying to fake it?

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386992). What's your actual goal, that you (almost certainly incorrectly) think this will let you accomplish?

Comment: What is an "Arch Linux"? If I install linux from scratch, and create a file `/etc/arch-release` - is it an archlinux? If I install 100 packages from archlinux repositories, and install 1000 from sources, is it still archlinux? How to differentiate "archlinux" from non-"archlinux" in an unambiguous, clear, exact way?

Comment: Ok, thank you for commenting about the XY problem @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica. The actual goal is to warn or ultimately throw an error if the OS detected at compile time is Arch Linux. The question of What is "Arch Linux"? Well, shouldn't Arch Linux represent itself as Arch Linux at some point? Why I'm using Arch Linux and not a "Linux from scratch with 100 packages from Arch Linux repositories"?

Comment: Okay, let's go up one more level: why is it important that your program only be *compiled* on Arch Linux?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica because my employer wants it to be an "Arch Linux only" software and "to restrict the project to only use the tools" (I guess implementations) "that, by default, comes with a fresh installation of Arch Linux". In other words, if something is not happening to work as expected under any OS/Distribution that is not Arch Linux, then is not our job to fix it or to give actual support as it is *unsupported*. I guess.

Edit: If this is completely impossible, then, I should really tell her that its is not viable, but I was wondering if there is any solution to this.

Comment: @arandompersonontheinternet I would say that, yes, this is completely impossible, and no, it is not viable.  It's a little like saying, "I want to write a book, in American English, that can be read only by people from the U.S. state of Georgia, who speak with a Southern accent.  I want to make sure that people with other accents can't/won't read my book."

Comment: If there are specific features that Arch Linux provides, that other distros do not, and that your program absolutely needs, you should find a way to check for the existence of those features.  If your employer wants to disallow use of other distros for purely political reasons, there are probably various ways to achieve it, but they'll be kludgey and not foolproof.

Comment: @SteveSummit You can always write in the first page of your book that it is intended to be read with a Southern accent as you were from Georgia. :)

Comment: @SteveSummit I don't think that the reason is just purely political, but to ensure the target as much as she can. I don't know.

Comment: 1. Do you want the program to only be _compilable_ under Arch Linux, or do you want it to be only _runnable_ on Arch Linux? Your question oscillates between the two. 2. How do you define Arch Linux? Does it include other distributions that are derivatives of Arch Linux?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' 1. My actual question is pretty clear, see "Question" in OP: But yes, I am talking about *compilation*.
2. If you ask me, Arch Linux is basically a Linux distribution, that is, the Linux kernel plus a specific collection of tools and libraries. If you ask my employer, I don't know. Does it include other distributions that are derivatives of Arch Linux? Yes.

Comment: Edit: However, yes, I mention "restrict from running". I am editing the OP so that it only mentions compilation. Sorry for that.

Comment: If you _compile_ on Arch, you can probably copy the executable to any other distro and _probably_ run just fine. If you want to restrict that, the program would have to "probe" the system at runtime (e.g. look at the `uname` _syscall_, check for existence of files unique to Arch (or non-existence of files not in Arch) or special contents of certain files. With the source code, it can be copied to any other distro and _compiled_ (e.g. there is no `#define _DISTRO_IS_ARCH_`). The build system could do the dynamic checks and prevent compilation but you can't use that(?)

Comment: But, the program doing dynamic checking can be thwarted by intercepting library calls / syscalls and returning spoofed info (via `LD_PRELOAD`). Or, no matter how complex the checks, they boil down to a single conditional asm jmp instruction (e.g. `jeq/jne`) than can be patched to always defeat the check. (Side note: In a job interview, I _got_ the job because I was able to say to the interviewer exactly what I just explained. The question was "how to defeat copy protection?").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does GCC (or alternatively Clang) defines any macro when it is compiled for the Arch Linux OS?

No. Because there's nothing inherently specific to Arch Linux on the binary level. For what it's worth, when compiling the only things you/the compiler has to care about is the target architecture (i.e. what kind of CPU it's going to run with), data type sizes and alignments and function calling conventions.

Then later on, when it's time to link the compiled translation unit objects into the final binary executable, the runtime libraries around are also of concern. Without taking special precautions you're essentially locking yourself into the specific brand of runtime libraries (glibc vs. e.g. musl; libstdc++ vs. libc++) pulled by the linker.

One can easily sidestep the later problem by linking statically, but that limits the range of system and midlevel APIs available to the program. For example on Linux a purely naively statically linked program wouldn't be able to use graphics acceleration APIs like OpenGL-3.x or Vulkan, since those rely on loading components of the GPU drivers into the process. You can however still use X11 and indirect GLX OpenGL, since those work using wire protocols going over sockets, which are implemented using direct syscalls to the kernel.

And these kernel syscalls are ***exactly the same*** on the binary level for each and every Linux kernel of every distribution out there. Although inside of the kernel there's a lot of leeway when it comes to redefining interfaces, when it comes to the interfaces toward the userland (i.e. regular programs) there's this holy, dogmatic, ironclad rule that ***YOU NEVER BREAK USERLAND!*** Kernel developers breaking this rule, intentionally or not are chewed out publicly by Linus Torvalds in his in-/famous rants.

The bottom line to this is, that there is no such thing as a "*Linux distribution specific identifier on the binary level*". At the end of the day, a Linux distribution is just that: A distribution of stuff. That means someone or more decided on a set of files that make up a working Linux system, wrap it up somehow and slap a name on it. That's it. There's nothing inherently specific to "Arch" Linux other than it's called "Arch" and (for the time being) relies on the *pacman* package manager. That's it. Everything else about "Arch", or any other Linux distribution, is just a matter of happenstance.

If you really want to sort different Linux distributions into certain bins regarding binary compatibility, then you'd have to pigeonhole the combinations of

- Minimum required set of supported syscalls. This translates into minimum required kernel version.
- What libc variant is being used; and potentially which version, although it's perfectly possible to link against a minimally supported set of functions, that has been around for almost "forever".
- What variant of the C++ standard library the distribution decided upon. This actually also inflicts programs that might appear to be purely C, because certain system level libraries (**cough** Mesa **cough**) will internally pull a lot of C++ infrastructure (even compilers), also triggering other "fun" problems¹

> I need to check that my software restricts itself from running under anything but Arch Linux (the reason behind this is off-topic). I couldn't find any relevant resources on the internet.

You couldn't find resources on the Internet, because there's nothing specific on the binary level that makes "Arch" Arch. For what it's worth right now, this instant I could create a fork of Arch, change out its choice of default XDG skeleton – so that by default user directories are populated with subdirs called `leech`, `flicks`, `beats`, `pics` – and call it "l33tz" Linux. For all intents and purposes it's no longer Arch. It does behave significantly different from the default Arch behavior, which would also be of concern to you, if you'd relied on *any* specific thing, and be it most minute.

Your employer doesn't seem to understand what Linux is or what distinguished distributions from each other.

Hint: It's not the binary compatibility. As a matter of fact, as long as you stay within the boring old realm of boring old *glibc* + *libstdc++* Linux distributions are shockingly compatible with each other. There might be slight differences in where they put libraries other than `libc.so`, `libdl.so` and `ld-linux[-${arch}].so`, but those two usually always can be found under `/lib`. And once `ld-linux[-${arch}].so` and `libdl.so` take over (that means pulling in all libraries loaded at runtime) all the specifics of where shared objects and libraries are to be found are abstracted away by the dynamic linker.

---

1: like becoming multithreaded only after global constructors were executed and libstdc++ deciding it wants to be singlethreaded, because libpthread wasn't linked into a program that didn't create a single thread on its own. That was a really weird bug I unearthed, but yshui finally understood https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/3199

Answer (score 2):

You can list the predefined preprocessor macros with

```
gcc -dM -E - /dev/null
clang -dM -E - /dev/null
```

None of those indicate what operating system the compiler is running under. So not only you can't tell whether the program is compiled under Arch Linux, you can't even tell whether the program is compiled under Linux. The macros `__linux__` and friends indicate that the program is being compiler *for* Linux. They are defined when cross-compiling from another system to Linux, and not defined when cross-compiling from Linux to another system.

You can artificially make your program more difficult to compile by specifying absolute paths for system headers and relying on non-portable headers (e.g. `/usr/include/bits/foo.h`). That can make cross-compilation or compilation for anything other than Linux practically impossible without modifying the source code. However, most Linux distributions install headers in the same location, so you're unlikely to pinpoint a specific distribution.

You're very likely [asking the wrong question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking *how* to restrict compilation to Arch Linux, start from *why* you want to restrict compilation to Arch Linux. If the answer is “because the resulting program wouldn't be what I want under another distribution”, then start from there and make sure that the difference results in a compilation error rather than incorrect execution. If the answer to “why” is something else, then you're probably looking for a technical solution to a social problem, and that rarely ends well.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. And even if it did, it wouldn't stop anyone from compiling the code on an Arch Linux distro and then running it on a different Linux.

If you need to prevent your software from "from running under anything but Arch Linux", you'll need to insert a run-time check. Although, to be honest, I have no idea what that check might consist of, since linux distros are not monolithic products. The actual check would probably have to do with your reasons for imposing the restriction.

Comment: I think `/etc/lsb-release`, or running the `lsb_release` command, are pretty standard.  It's not hard for the user to fake it if they really want to, of course.

Comment: @nate: sure, but that avoids the question of what, precisely, constitutes an "Arch Linux OS". In fact, the OS is not specific to Arch Linux; it's just a Linux kernel of a particular version with particular build options which of course vary from release to release. Arch Linux is a collection of associated software, from kernel modules to applications, none of which are specific to Arch; the value added by the distro is a vague reassurance that the different packages will more or less happily coexist. But I'm free to install (or remove) whatever I want. So at what point does it ...

Comment: ...stop being Arch Linux? Is "when `/etc/lsb-release`is modified an adequate answer?" Hence the last sentence in my answer: check what you care about; not just a label.